# importing excel file into UI using pyqt4

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-creator, qt-designer

how to display a spreadsheet in a widget when a button is pressed in another widget?
I'm a new bee in using QT user interface design.!
how to perform File operations.? i..e to perform read and write operations on the same file from the interface.?

Answer (score 1):

First of all have a look at: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

this will lead you to the first hints of what you can do with `Qt` classes.
The next thing you need to think of is, do you want to use `QTableWidget` or `QTableView` and a `Q...Model` to display your data and let the user modify it.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html

For file operations have a look at: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html

I've used the c++ links because afaik there is no big difference between `PyQt` and `Qt(in c++)`.

cheers